# How can find format number by Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

This my text=`0.123.456Vaaa.789.V`

I want find text=`123.456V`

I using this pattern in C#: `\.[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*V`

But result return 2 values: `123.456V` and `789.V`

I don't want get case blank after `"."`: `789.V`

How can fix my pattern?

Thank you.

Comment: the last asterisk says that there does not need to be a digit after the dot. You could try changing the `*` to `+`.

Comment: Use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?V`

Comment: @René Vogt , thank you. it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern, `[\.]?` does not have to be a separate character class, or the dot does not have to be escaped. I suggest writing the optional dot pattern as `\.?`, it is least ambiguous. `[0-9]*` after the optional dot pattern matches zero or more digits, hence you get unexpected matches.

You do not seem to need the `\.` at the start, either.

You can use

```cs
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+V
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5d*%5c.%3f%5b0-9%5d%2bV&i=0.123.456Vaaa.789.V).

*Details*:

- `[0-9]*` - zero or more ASCII digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `V` - a `V` char.

See a [C# regex demo](https://ideone.com/TanJpv):

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+V")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();

// => 123.456V
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be:

`\d+\.\d+V`

meaning you want to find some arbitrary number of digits, followed by a dot, followed by more digits, followed by the letter V.

Comment: thank you, but my case [.456V] is a valid number.

Comment: ahh okay, sorry I misunderstood